# How can I SELECT based on both a NOT EQUAL and a NOT EXISTS query in Oracle with complex FROM Tables

Tags: oracle

**I want to combine BOTH of these queries into ONE query that returns ALL results from EITHER**

---

### Query A:

```
SELECT prsn.prsn_id, person_points.points
  FROM persons prsn,
       (SELECT prsn_id prsn_id, sum(points) points
          FROM (SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       invoices inv,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       orders ord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id     = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.inv_id      = inv.inv_id
                   AND inv.ord_id       = ord.ord_id
                   AND ord.prsn_id_byr  = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       reward_order_details rdet,
                       reward_orders rord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND rdet.rdet_id     = pnts.rdet_id
                   AND rord.rord_id     = rdet.rord_id
                   AND rord.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       miscellaneous_points misp,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND pnts.mpts_id     = misp.mpts_id
                   AND misp.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       returns rtn,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id    = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.rtn_id     = rtn.rtn_id
                   AND rtn.prsn_id_byr = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id)
        GROUP BY prsn_id) person_points
 WHERE person_points.points > 0
   AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
   AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM point_summaries x
                     WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```

---

### Query B

```
SELECT prsn.prsn_id, person_points.points, psum.psum_points_available
  FROM persons prsn,
       point_summaries psum,
       (SELECT prsn_id prsn_id, sum(points) points
          FROM (SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       invoices inv,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       orders ord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id     = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.inv_id      = inv.inv_id
                   AND inv.ord_id       = ord.ord_id
                   AND ord.prsn_id_byr  = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       reward_order_details rdet,
                       reward_orders rord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND rdet.rdet_id     = pnts.rdet_id
                   AND rord.rord_id     = rdet.rord_id
                   AND rord.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       miscellaneous_points misp,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND pnts.mpts_id     = misp.mpts_id
                   AND misp.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       returns rtn,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id    = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.rtn_id     = rtn.rtn_id
                   AND rtn.prsn_id_byr = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id)
        GROUP BY prsn_id) person_points
 WHERE person_points.points > 0
   AND prsn.prsn_id = psum.prsn_id
   AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
   AND NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points
```

---

The main chunk of these statements Union all the different areas Reward Points can be calculated in our system attach those sums to a person id and then output the current total points reported, and what they should be via the calculation.

The point of this is to find all Persons in our system and correct any incorrectly calculated reward points.

These can be incorrect in two ways:

1. The total calculated reward points are different than the `points_summary.psum_points_available`
2. The total calculated rewards points exist, but the point_summary row with a correlating `prsn_id` does not exist yet.

The main differences in the two Queries are here:

### Query A

```
WHERE person_points.points > 0
  AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM point_summaries x
                    WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```

### Query B

```
WHERE person_points.points > 0
  AND prsn.prsn_id = psum.prsn_id
  AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  AND NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points
```

---

Query **A** Returns:

```
| prsn_id | points       |
|------------------------|
|111111   | 169          |
|111112   | 104          |
|111113   | 116          |
|111114   | 219          |
|111114   | 88           |
|111115   | 395          |
|111115   | 35           |
```

Query **B** Returns:

```
| prsn_id | points | psum_points_available |
|------------------------------------------|
| 111111  | 676    | 287                   |
| 111111  | 11672  | 1971                  |
| 111111  | 137    | 89                    |
| 111111  | 156    | 78                    |
| 111111  | 5111   | 570                   |
| 111111  | 280    | 193                   |
```

---

I would like to combine these two queries into one, and get an output that looks something like this:

What I would like the **COMBINED** query to return:

```
| prsn_id | points | psum_points_available |
|------------------------------------------|
| 111111  | 100    | NULL or 0             |
| 111112  | 11672  | 1971                  |
| 111113  | 137    | 89                    |
| 111114  | 156    | NULL or 0             |
| 111114  | 5111   | NULL or 0             |
| 111115  | 280    | 193                   |
```

I attempted to combine with an OR statement like this:

### Query COMBINED

```
WHERE person_points.points > 0
  AND psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  AND ((psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
        AND NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points)
       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM ci_point_summaries x
                       WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```

However this is returning:

```
| prsn_id | points | psum_points_available |
|------------------------------------------|
| 111111  | 676    | 38                    |
| 111112  | 676    | 40                    |
| 111113  | 676    | 0                     |
| 111114  | 676    | 33                    |
| 111115  | 676    | 420                   |
| 111116  | 676    | 35                    |
| 111117  | 676    | 60                    |
```

Notice how the calculated points (labeled **points**) are the same for every row.

---

I have been staring at this too long and can't figure out why. I have to be just making a simple error somewhere as this is very nearly where I want it. I am new to SQL (~1 month of work) and can not find the nuance of what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than `FROM` multiple tables.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum on psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  WHERE person_points.points > 0
    AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
    AND ((NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points)
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM point_summaries x
                        WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```

This allowed me to get the results I desired with a (null) in the `psum.psum_points_available` with the `OR` clause.

---

#### Full Query:

```
SELECT prsn.prsn_id, person_points.points, psum.psum_points_available
  FROM (SELECT prsn_id prsn_id, sum(points) points
          FROM (SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       invoices inv,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       orders ord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id     = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.inv_id      = inv.inv_id
                   AND inv.ord_id       = ord.ord_id
                   AND ord.prsn_id_byr  = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       reward_order_details rdet,
                       reward_orders rord,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND rdet.rdet_id     = pnts.rdet_id
                   AND rord.rord_id     = rdet.rord_id
                   AND rord.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                       UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       miscellaneous_points misp,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND pnts.mpts_id     = misp.mpts_id
                   AND misp.prsn_id     = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT prsn.prsn_id, SUM(pnts.pnts_points) points
                  FROM points pnts,
                       transaction_details tdet,
                       returns rtn,
                       persons prsn
                 WHERE pnts.pnts_status = 'R'
                   AND tdet.tdet_id    = pnts.tdet_id
                   AND tdet.rtn_id     = rtn.rtn_id
                   AND rtn.prsn_id_byr = prsn.prsn_id
              GROUP BY prsn.prsn_id)
        GROUP BY prsn_id) person_points,
        persons prsn
LEFT OUTER JOIN point_summaries psum on psum.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
  WHERE person_points.points > 0
    AND person_points.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
    AND ((NOT psum.psum_points_available = person_points.points)
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM point_summaries x
                        WHERE x.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id))
```